# RoR: rake db:seed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Most likely a nooby question here but I'm stuck regardless. I'm trying to set up some information in a database and the rake db:seed errors out on me and I can't figure out why.

My error message:

```
[tomos@Helix swipeApp]$ rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-            4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1258:in `has_many'
/home/tomos/Dropbox/EventsApp/WebApp/swipeApp/app/models/tag.rb:4:in `<class:Tag>'
/home/tomos/Dropbox/EventsApp/WebApp/swipeApp/app/models/tag.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
/home/tomos/Dropbox/EventsApp/WebApp/swipeApp/db/seeds.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/tomos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

db/migrate/20150902195742_create_tags.rb:

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.string :image
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/20150902195921_create_events.rb:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.string :image
        t.string :description
        t.references :tag
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is app/models/tag.rb:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
        ActiveRecord::Base
                has_many
        :destinations
end
```

And finally my db/seeds.rb:

```
t1 = Tag.create(title: "Tag 1", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"))
Event.create(name: "Event 1", description: "Event 1 is gonna blow ur mind.", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t1.id)
Event.create(name: "Event 2", description: "Holy shit this is incredibles.", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t1.id)
Event.create(name: "Event 3", description: "Yummy tasty event 3 description here", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t1.id)
t2 = Tag.create(title: "Tag 1", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"))
Event.create(name: "Event 1", description: "Event 1 is gonna blow ur mind.", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t2.id)
Event.create(name: "Event 2", description: "Holy shit this is incredibles.", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t2.id)
Event.create(name: "Event 3", description: "Yummy tasty event 3 description here", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t2.id)
t3 = Tag.create(title: "Tag 1", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"))
Event.create(name: "Event 1", description: "Event 1 is gonna blow ur mind.", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t3.id)
Event.create(name: "Event 2", description: "Holy shit this is incredibles.", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t3.id)
Event.create(name: "Event 3", description: "Yummy tasty event 3   description here", image: File.new("image/to/path.jpg"), tag_id: t3.id)
```

Let me know if I'm missing any important information. Many thanks!

Comment: I guess you have pending migrations. Try rake db:migrate and then do rake db:seed

Comment: Tried that, but thankyou

Comment: could you show us `app/models/tag.rb` specialy line `4`.

Comment: Ahhh yeah you're a badass - corrected :destinations to :events and put it on the same line as has_many and it all works smoothly now. - You can put this as the solution and I'll mark it correct. Cheers

Comment: Out of interest how could you tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your error message, especially line 4:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)
# some message here
/home/tomos/Dropbox/EventsApp/WebApp/swipeApp/app/models/tag.rb:4:in `<class:Tag>'
# some message here
```